# Printer set-up in Ubuntu13.10: printer can not create temporary file

Tags: printing

I recently upgraded a system from 12.4 to 13.10. LaserJet 4p printer connect to LPT1 was working under 12.04, now when I send even test page to printer, job comes up in the printer queue but is stopped.  When get details, it states that:

```
Can't create temporary file
```

What I don't have sufficient information to troubleshoot. Any and all assistance is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this:
http://www.emmestech.com/linux/problems.html

Solution:
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp

So the permissions on the /tmp folder were wrong. In my case I've changed the mount and did not realise the implications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried answer above in Debian Buster but it doesn't work. My problem solved when I changed ownership of /var/spool/cups/ directory. It was root:lp and I changed it to lp:lp. The printer starts to work immediately.